# Is there a camera lock option on replays?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I know L locks the camera but I seem to be unable to use that in replays. What I can do is click on the hero icon and hold pressing space to lock the camera. Do I have any other options?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the current state of the game (Thrall Patch), there is no camera lock option and pressing space is the only way to go for now.